# How to mount a broken usb that just can be detected with 'dmesg' (with terminal) but not shows the /dev/usb file

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, kde

Loading with *Rufus* a Windows-Image in a USB, it was damaged, ceasing to be recognized by the system. Neither windows nor ubuntu can detect it. I've tried using Windows disk partition editor, the Rufus software itself, KDE partition (I'm using KDE Neon)... and nothing, none of these attempts have worked.

Finally I've been able to detect something with the terminal thanks to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/290378/1568895) post. Basically it uses `sudo lsusb` for listing the devices. In my terminal I can see the broken usb in the penultimate line:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0eef:c0aa D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd eGalaxTouch EXC3104-1324-07.00.00
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:e007 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5696 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 1f75:0817 Innostor Technology Corporation USB 2.0
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But then, when it's time to use `dmesg` I can't see the /dev/ assignment:

```
[12020.461164] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
[12020.610146] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1f75, idProduct=0817, bcdDevice= 0.01
[12020.610159] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[12020.610165] usb 1-1: Product: USB 2.0
[12020.610168] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: innostor
[12020.610172] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 0012343171372180
[12022.483384] usb 1-1: can't set config #1, error -71
```

And because of this when the post talks about mounting the filesystem I don't know exactly what to do. I've tried [this](https://superuser.com/a/1047847) with the given information by `dmesg`. A new file call hiddev0 has appeared in /dev/usb/ then I've tried to mount it in /media/usb-drive (with `sudo mount /dev/usb/hiddev0 /media/usb-drive/`) but the answer is
`mount: /media/usb-drive: /dev/usb/hiddev0 is not a block device`.

Thanks in advance.

More helpful information.
Running `usb-devices`:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#= 20 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1f75 ProdID=0817 Rev=00.01
S:  Manufacturer=innostor
S:  Product=USB 2.0
S:  SerialNumber=0012343171372180
C:  #Ifs= 0 Cfg#= 0 Atr= MxPwr=
cat: '/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/1-1/1-*:?.*/bInterfaceNumber': No such file or directory
cat: '/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/1-1/1-*:?.*/bAlternateSetting': No such file or directory
cat: '/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/1-1/1-*:?.*/bNumEndpoints': No such file or directory
cat: '/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/1-1/1-*:?.*/bInterfaceClass': No such file or directory
cat: '/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/1-1/1-*:?.*/bInterfaceSubClass': No such file or directory
cat: '/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/1-1/1-*:?.*/bInterfaceProtocol': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/usb-devices: 76: printf: (none): expected numeric value
I:  If#=0x Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=() Sub= Prot= Driver=
```

Comment: There is no magical way to repair a "broken usb". Also, why take pictures of "console output", and not just copy/paste?

Comment: Wise words. Console output pictures vs copy/paste fixed. Thanks

Comment: And KDE Neon is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the information you have provided, it looks like there is a problem with the firmware.

As you mentioned, `lsusb` command is listing your device, thereby it is detecting it. But when you run the command `lsblk`, it does not detect your usb as a block device.

I'm not an expert with this, but it looks like the problem could be with the firmware and the driver associated with it.

Finally, nowadays, USBs have become extremely cheap. You can find USBs with 32GB storage for less than 10.

Comment: The OS being used is not supported on this site.